# PassBookUiService quit unexpectedly

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, applepay

i am implementing apple pay with stripe. I followed official documents of stripe. so Whenever i clicked a buy with apple button it doesn't show the payment sheet. and it show's an error like

> "passbookUiSevice quit unexpectedly".

and also Connection to remote alert view service failed,

> Failed to present in-app payment interface: Error
>   Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=-1 "Payment interface not available"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Payment interface not available.

and when running the same code in Macbookair in simulator it works very well but it doesn't work in imac. i don't know what is the problem. How to solve that error.